# Android app crashes when wifi enable/disable

Tags: android, networking, crash, wifi, broadcast

I am developing the app which requires an internet connection. When I enable or disable the wifi, the app crashes. I could not find any solution for this issue. I observe it by broadcast receiver. I got network status on receive method. But then it crashes. Any trick or suggest I can explore for this issue?

Comment: please post your logcat output

Comment: make sure you have given INTERNET permission in manifiest

Answer (score 1):

Add the permission in the manifest: `<android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE/>`